# Attaching files to OmniFocus

Tags: omnifocus

If I drag a file into an OmniFocus task, it will create a link to that file. Is there a way to actually place the file inside the task instead of just creating a link?

Answer (score 1):

1st way: Hold Alt/Option while dragging.

2nd way: Select file in Finder and press your clippings shortcut